# Adding image as watermark to responsive content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the page content like below. And when the product stock is not available I need to add a image as watermark saying out of stock. how can I do this?  See sample image. Also this box sizes are not fixed. it's dynamic. because in mobile devices the box size is more wider and stack one by one (not in a row). So in that case I can't use position as absolute.
[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="row">
        description about product
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        Select how many you want.
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         Out of Stock

     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo element to add the "out of stock" image.

**html:**

```
<div class="box1 outofstock">
</div>
<div class="box2 outofstock">
</div>
<div class="box3 outofstock">
</div>
<div class="box4 outofstock">
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div.outofstock:after {
  background: transparent url(http://www.computingsystem.in/img/outofstock.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #800;
  position: relative;
}
.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box4 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufktcas1/

I made the boxes different sizes so you can see how they look depending on the size.

Additionally, you can also opt to not use an image:
https://jsfiddle.net/ufktcas1/1/

In your case the `.outofstock` class should be added to the `col-sm-12` element. However `col-sm-12` must have `position: relative;` for it to work.

Comment: Yes, to see it in mobile view, I need to have `position:relative` so in that case, i don't see the images in desktop view. also in the mobile view, the images are not in the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If height remain same on all screen resolutions you can try same height image as other box have and to make image center you can use text-align:center; or display:block; margin: 0 auto;

Comment: but where should I put it? which row? if I put it to last row. then image doesn't cover the other rows. See the sample. The image is like covering all three rows. just on top of the text. Can you give me compete code to ge that output?

Answer (score 0):

I used below settings as DigitalDouble said. And call this out-of-stock-img class in the `<div class="col-sm-12 out-of-stock-img">`

```
.out-of-stock-img:after{
   background: transparent url("../images/out-of-stock.png") no-repeat center;
   background-size: contain;
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: 78%;
   width: 93%;
   bottom: 13px;
}
```